# How can I read the contents of all the files in a directory with pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a folder with lots of `.txt` files. How can I read all the files in the folder and get the content of them with pandas?. I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
list_=pd.read_csv("/path/of/the/directory/*.txt",header=None)
print list_
```

Comment: Do you want to read them all into the same DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, I would like to treat all the files as one. @ajcr

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import glob

l = [pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in glob.glob("/path/*.txt")]
df = pd.concat(l, axis=0)
```

You have to take into account the header, for example if you want to ignore it take a look at the skiprows option in [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html).

Answer (score 1):

**I used this in my project for merging the csv files**

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path = "path of the file"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if not file.startswith('.')]
all_data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
current_data = pd.read_csv(path+"/"+file ,  encoding = "ISO-8859-1")  
all_data = pd.concat([all_data,current_data])
```

Comment: The question already has an accepted answer - consider adding an explanation of why you believe your answer is more helpful.

Comment: This answer provides value as it is an alternative for developers that does not have the formatting into account.