# Navigate and append csv from child directories

Tags: python, r, dataframe, navigation

I am in a directory that holds 36 different folders. Each folder has a single csv in it. I want to append each of these together to make a large data frame in python.

in R, I would do this:

```r
cwd = getwd() #get current directory
fil = list.files() #get list of all files/folders in the directory
Bigdf = NULL #initialize empty df
for(i in fil){ #read through all folders in current directory
    setwd(paste0(cwd,'/',i)) #navigate to i'th folder
    fil2 = list.files() #get list of files in i'th folder
    for(j in fil2){
        a = read.csv(paste0(cwd,'/',i,'/',j)) #read in all csv's 
        Bigdf = rbind(Bigdf,a[,c(2,4:11)]) #append desired columns to data frame
    }
    setwd(cwd) 
}
```

How would I go about doing something like this in python?

I tried to implement [How can I read the contents of all the files in a directory with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749553/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-all-the-files-in-a-directory-with-pandas) and [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory) and to no avail. I think I am missing something obvious, and hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the modules `os` (e.g. `os.listdir`) and `csv`.

Comment: that was it, thanks for the direction

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

li =[]

for filename in glob.iglob('src/**/*.csv', recursive=True):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Combination of

[Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe)

and

[How to use glob() to find files recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186525/how-to-use-glob-to-find-files-recursively)